# Avro logicalType for Date is giving exception : java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Date cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number

Tags: java, spring-boot, datetime, avro, jsonschema

My question in related to avro schema.
I have java pojo like below

```
public class demo {
    private Date startedAt;
    private Date completedAt;
}
```

I have generated avro schema for above class like below:

```
{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "demo",
  "fields": [
    {
      "name": "startedAt",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "completedAt",
      "type": {
        "type": "long",
        "logicalType": "timestamp-millis"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using avro veriosn 1.10.0 but it seems logicalType not working for me.
I'm getting below error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class java.util.Date cannot be cast to class java.lang.Number (java.util.Date and java.lang.Number are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeWithoutConversion(GenericDatumWriter.java:157) \~\[avro-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0\]
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.write(GenericDatumWriter.java:81) \~\[avro-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0\]
at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.write(ReflectDatumWriter.java:159) \~\[avro-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0\]
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeField(GenericDatumWriter.java:221) \~\[avro-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0\]
at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeField(SpecificDatumWriter.java:110) \~\[avro-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0\]
at org.apache.avro.reflect.ReflectDatumWriter.writeField(ReflectDatumWriter.java:185) \~\[avro-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0\]
at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumWriter.writeRecord(GenericDatumWriter.java:210) \~\[avro-1.11.0.jar:1.11.0\]
at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificDatumWriter.writeRecord(SpecificDatumWriter.java:84) ....
```

Can someone suggest solution for above problem.
Thanks in advance!

I tried different logicalType but none of them is working.
Kindly suggest me if I'm doing is correct way or not.

Comment: I would say it should be "logicalType": "date".

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response.
I tried by changing "logicalType": "date as below
{
      "name": "startedAt",
      "type": {
        "type": "int",
        "logicalType": "date"
      }
    }

Still getting same exception.
I'm passing "demo" class as kafka request and while serializing getting the exception.

Comment: Which value serializer have you configured in kafka properties?

Comment: Should be io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer. And schema need to be present in the schema registry.

Comment: Sorry. We can't work this way... Code in comment is not readable. And if you have a custom serializer then you should test it. We can't do it for you here on SO.